# Caching a class method result on a request

Tags: caching, pyramid

I have a following structure:

```
class Entry:
     def has_items(self, request: Request) -> bool:
         pass
```

What would be Pyramistic approach to cache the evaluation `has_items()` so that

- It is evaluated only once per request
- The cache key is the entry instance itself (`id(entry)`)
- The cache storage could (naturally?) be on the request object itself

Comment: Could it be that you look for http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_request_method ?

Answer (score 1):

As matino already stated, I also think the `config.add_request_method` is the way to do this.  I have in my code the following:

```
config.add_request_method(get_current_user_groups, 'groups', reify=True)
```

This makes a single call to `get_current_user_groups` with the `request` as the only argument.  The `reify=True` tells it to cache the result as a property.  Now, any call to `request.groups` gives me a list of the groups for that user.

I'm not sure, but I think the method may be "lazy loaded" in that the call is only made after the first call to read the property is made.

Comment: Nice one. The problem this approach is that I don't want to pollute request object namespace with methods which really do not belong there.

Comment: Ah.. well, you could also use the `reify` decorator (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/decorator.html)

Comment: It may be a good aproach since your method `has_items` already depends on the request (not sure if it's a good design though). Alternatively you could use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_dogpile_cache/0.0.4 or https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_beaker and implement your own caching strategy.